# How to use paginate_orphans in django function based views?

Tags: django, django-views, django-pagination

**In Class-Based View We Can Use Like This.**

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name ='blog/index.html'
    ordering = ['id']
    paginate_by = 5
    paginate_orphans = 2
```

**But How can I Use this `paginate_orphans` in function-based views?**

```
page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
paginator = Paginator(filter_qs, 2)
try:
   filter_qs = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
   filter_qs = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
   filter_qs = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Comment: Pass the `orphans` argument to your paginator: `paginator = Paginator(filter_qs, 5, orphans=2)` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/paginator/#django.core.paginator.Paginator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass orphans parameter to the Paginator class as mentioned below:

```
paginator = Paginator(filter_qs, 2, orphans=2)
```